# Adjusting the width for tinymce buttons on header?

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg

i have used below code snippet to show the different features like forecolor,backcolor,bulllist etc on tinymce

```
 $(function() {
  appendTinyMCE();
 function appendTinyMCE(){
    tinyMCE.init({

        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "preview",
        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "forecolor,backcolor,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,bullist,numlist,|,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect,sub,sup,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true

});}
```

});

But when i see the tinymce on browser, around 25 percent of tinymce editor header width is taken by just two buttons i.e forecolor,backcolor 
which looks very odd , though i have mentioned   theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left". 
here is the image.

[image]

**Can  we adjust the tinymce buttons so 
that each button takes uniform width?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the css of the tinymce toolbar using the tinymce init configuration paramter [editor_css](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-appearance/).

Comment: Hi Thariama, i tried changing couple of options in ui.css under advanced/skins/default folder like background-position:-720px , but could not align first two options (i.e forecolor and backcolor) in left.It would be really helpful if  can provide more inuts?

Comment: you should never change core code like ui.css, instead create a custom css file and include it int he editor using the editor_css setting. can you recreate the problem using a tinymce fiddle? (http://fiddle.tinymce.com/)

Comment: Hi Thariama can you provide your inputs on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629579/tinymce-image-drag-and-drop-issue-on-internet-explorer