# Tinymce Image drag and drop issue on Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, web-applications, tinymce, wysiwyg

i have html page  where i am using tinymce editor. when i open the mockup in firefox browser and now drag/drop an jpg image 
at any position in tinymce editor, it gets inserted  correctly. But when i do the same process in IE/Chrome browser, the moment
i dropped an image, it does not place the image inside tinymce editor instead the whole browser relocates to the url of the image. 
**I am not able to understand why image is not
placed inside tinymce editor when html page is opened up in IE and chrome browser(though it is placed correctly in IE/Chrome)?
What is the workaround to place the jpg image correctly inside tinymce editor for IE9/Chrome?**

Here  is the post i got related to it

http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=23597

I tried what ryanreeves post suggested for solution.  This is what i did . I created one css file with name myCustomCSSFile.css which has below content

```
html, body { height:100% }
```

now in my tinymce code i refered it as below

```
tinyMCE.init({
     mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "advlist",
    content_css : "myCustomCSSFile.css",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "forecolor,backcolor,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect,sub,sup,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true

  });
```

For information, i have placed the css file i.e myCustomCSSFile.css at the same location where my html(which has above tinymce code) file is lying.
this is suggested at as per http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:content_css

Also posted to tinymce forum also at http://www.tinymce.com/forum/post.php?fid=1 but no help.

Comment: i think there has been some adjustments to the latest drag & drop handling in the neweer tinymce version, which version are you using?

Comment: Hi, Did you some how get your issue solved?