# Dropping the image inside WYSWYG editor in IE/Chrome?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, drag-and-drop, tinymce, wysiwyg

When i drop any image in my WYSWYG  editor(tinymce in my case) in IE/Chrome, IE does not seem to support it.The moment i drop the image in WYSWYG  editor(contained in my html page) , whole browser relocates to the url of the image(basically it does not paste the image inside editor but opens the image as if i am dropping the image on empty IE browser not inside editor)? Though in firefox, image gets embedded correctly inside editor. I am not able to figure out do i have set some explicit property to make it work like in IE? i am doing googling from last one day but has not got solution yet.

This is the nutshell of problem.For in and out of issue , here is the link [Tinymce Image drag and drop issue on Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629579/tinymce-image-drag-and-drop-issue-on-internet-explorer) . But now looks like its an issue with browser rather than editor but not sure?

**EDIT:- Folks Looks like its an issue with IE not editor. To ensure this i opened my gmail in firefox and drag/drop the image inside email body, it embedded correctly. When i do the same in IE, complete browser relocates to the url of the image instead of embedding in gmail mail body. Now  i do not have clue what change i need to do in my code to make it work in IE?**

Comment: You already postded a question about this that mentions the problem with IE. What is the purpose of this new question?

Comment: That question had much details about tinymce .Probably that was confusing the users and has not got any replies yet.So thought of making the post simple.Will link both of them together once i get related inputs on any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only IE10 allows to upload images to a WYSIWYG editor by drag&drop.

Firefox by default embeds them as data: (which is not good to keep the page size down, and it's not understood by old browsers), and you need to add extra code to handle them in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Hi AlfonsoML i can use either IE8/IE9 not IE10 because of our product restriction. Can you point me how can i handle the drop image functionality in IE8/IE9?

Comment: As I said, only IE 10 (currently in beta so it's not a good idea to suggest that to clients) allows that functionality. You can't make it work in IE8/IE9.